# RadioButtons in Firemonkey are all checked after scrolled out of view

Tags: delphi, radio-button, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I have a problem with the radio buttons in FireMonkey.

Whenever they are scrolled out of view, then they are all checked.

[image: Radio Button in Firemnokey all checked after scroll.]

The problem seems to be alone graphical conditional, because he remembers which button is really checked.

GroupName already set.

Some ideas?

Comment: FireMonkey is something of a bug factory. So the Delphi version you use may well be very important.

Comment: My Version is Embarcadero® Delphi® XE5 Version 19.0.14356.6604